# When I try to duplicate an object with shift + d it doesn't work cause the controls change inmediately to the timeline

Tags: modeling

So after trying to duplicate an object with shift + d, when you scroll, for example, instead of zoom it changes the timeline.
Has anyone an idea of why is this happening? and how can I fix this to be able to duplicate objects with shift + d?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you modify the keyboard shortcut settings at all?

Comment: Stuck keys? Faulty keyboard? Bad window focus?

Answer (score 5):

**If you want to manipulate objects in 3D-view, your cursor has to stay inside that area for shortcuts to work .**

The only standard explanation I know would be that you are not in the right area. Blender uses a concept called implicit focus. It means that the active area is the one below your mouse cursor. That saves you a lot of clicking but it can also mean that keyboard shortcuts won't work or do different things if your cursor is misplaced by accident.